# Ajax jQuery autocomplete call to local postal company

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I've recently taken over a project for an enrolment form and they have used the Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery calling the local post shops api to complete addresses for school applications. What I am trying to do is seperate out the information to insert into a FileMaker database.

The code:

```
$.each($('.address_lookup'), function(i, lookup) {
  $(lookup).autocomplete({
   serviceUrl: '<?php echo site_url(); ?>enrolment/ajax_address_search',
   onSelect: function (suggestion) {
   $($(lookup).data('id')).val(suggestion.data);
   $.ajax('<?php echo site_url(); ?>enrolment/ajax_address_lookup/'+suggestion.data)
   .done(function(address) {
     var street = address;
     var unitNumber = $("#Home_Address_Flat_Unit").val(address.UnitValue);
     var streetAddress = $("#Home_Address_Num_Street").val(address.StreetNumber);
     var postCode = $("#Home_Address_Postcode").val(address.PostCode);
     var suburb = $("#Home_Address_Suburb").val(address.Suburb);
     var town = $("#Home_Address_Town").val(address.Town);
     var rdNumber = $("#Home_Address_RD").val(address.RDNumber);
     });
    }
  });
});
```

The console log output of **address**

```
{
    "BuildingName":null,
    "CompanyName":"",
    "DepotName":"AKL Western Suburbs Fleet",
    "Floor":null,
    "GatedCommunityFlag":null,
    "Latitude":-36.8208,
    "Longitude":174.64,
    "PostCode":"0618",
    "RDFlag":"N",
    "RDNumber":null,
    "RateableSuburbID":15450,
    "RunNumber":"ACP104  ",
    "Street":"Da Vinci",
    "StreetAlpha":null,
    "StreetNumber":9,
    "StreetType":"Place",
    "Suburb":"West Harbour",
    "SuburbID":2905,
    "Town":"Auckland",
    "UnitType":null,
    "UnitValue":null
}
```

I'm wanting to break it apart to insert the `Postcode`, `Streetnumber`, etc. into hidden fields. My attempt is visible in this section:

```
var rdNumber = $('#Home_Address_RD').val(address.RDNumber);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I take it rdNumber is *null* - since it is in the data received - what exactly is the issue?

Comment: RDNumber stands for if it is a Rural Delivery address..
I'm not sure how to seperate the string into seperate fields. It's all going into the same field at the moment.

Comment: RDNumber is **null** in your example - what do you expect to "split"?

Comment: Each of those results into seperate fields. They are in a single string. I don't think that split() would be the best option... I couldn't be wrong through. Each unit is represented as a seperate unit in the database.

Comment: oh, `address = JSON.parse(address)` is what you need, if address is a string

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for that!

Comment: NZ Post? Have fun with that API - there's a bunch of coalesces that I've done in a PHP adapter I've written to fill details into a more sane address format.